# Simplifying $I = \int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2} d\phi \left[ 1-M(\phi) \theta^*(\phi) \right]$

Tags: integration

I am stuck at simplifying the following integral:
$$
I = 
\int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}
d\phi
\left[
1-M(\phi) \theta^*(\phi)
\right]
$$
where
$
M= 
p \cos \phi + q \sin \phi
$.
Here $p,q$ are fixed.

The $\theta^\star$ is defined through
$\cos \theta^*=
\frac{M}{\sqrt{1+M^2}}
$

Can anybody help me to clarify things?
I have reason to believe it should take a much nicer form.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
The integral writes
$
I=
\pi-
I_1$
where
$I_1
=
\int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}
d\phi
M(\phi) \theta^*(\phi)
$

Using integration by parts as suggested,
we obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
u
=\theta^*(\phi)
=\arccos G
&\Rightarrow&
du
=
\frac{-dG}{\sqrt{1-G^2}}=
-\sqrt{1+M^2}dG=
\frac{-A}{(1+M^2)}d\phi \\
dv=M(\phi) d\phi
&\Rightarrow&
v
=
-A
\end{eqnarray}

Let $G=\frac{M}{\sqrt{1+M^2}}$
thus
$dG
=\frac{1}{(1+M^2)^{3/2}}dM
=\frac{A}{(1+M^2)^{3/2}}d\phi
$

where
$
A(\phi)=
M'(\phi)=
q\cos \phi-p\sin \phi$.

Note that $A^2+M^2=p^2+q^2$.

Introduce $\alpha=\sqrt{p^2+q^2+1}$

Thus the integral writes
\begin{eqnarray}
I_1
&=&
\left[
-\theta^* A
\right]_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}
-
\int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}
d\phi
\frac{A^2}{1+M^2} \\
&=&
p\pi
-
\int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}
d\phi
\frac{A^2}{\alpha^2-A^2} \\
&=&
p\pi
+\pi
-
\int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}
d\phi
\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2-A^2}
\end{eqnarray}

I have reasons to think that the right integral simplifies into
$$
\int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}
d\phi
\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2-A^2}
=
\alpha \pi 
$$
but I could not manage to prove it.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: With an $\arccos$ involved, my first thought is to use integration by parts to take the derivative of that $\arccos$. So $u = \theta^*(\phi)$, $dv = M(\phi)\, d\phi$.